# I need to take an element with Jquery in this HTML

Tags: jquery, html

This is the HTML a part of all HTML code that I have in my program.

```
<li component="category/topic" class="row clearfix pinned" data-tid="1" data-index="2" data-cid="2" itemprop="itemListElement">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Welcome to your NodeBB!">

    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-xs-10 content">
        <div class="avatar pull-left" data-original-title="" title="">
                            <div class="select" component="topic/select">
                                    <div class="user-icon" style="background-color: #673ab7;" title="" data-original-title="admin">A</div>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h2 component="topic/header" class="title">
            (I NEED TO REMOVE THIS LINE) <i component="topic/pinned" class="fa fa-thumb-tack "></i>
            <i component="topic/locked" class="fa fa-lock hide"></i>
                            <a href="/topic/1/welcome-to-your-nodebb" itemprop="url">Welcome to your NodeBB!</a><br>



            <span class="tag-list hidden-xs">


            </span>

            <small class="hidden-xs"><span class="timeago" title="Fri Aug 05 2016 11:44:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)">25 days ago</span></small>
            <small class="visible-xs-inline">
                                    <span class="timeago" title="Mon Aug 29 2016 16:39:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)">about 19 hours ago</span>
            </small>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="mobile-stat col-xs-2 visible-xs text-right">
        <span class="human-readable-number">2</span> <a href="/topic/1/welcome-to-your-nodebb/2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs stats">
        <span class="human-readable-number" title="2">2</span><br>
        <small>Posts</small>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs stats">
        <span class="human-readable-number" title="6">6</span><br>
        <small>Views</small>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 teaser hidden-xs">
        <div class="card" style="border-color: #59b3d0">
                                            <p>
                <a href="/user/admin">
                                            <span title="" class="user-icon user-img" style="background-color: #673ab7;" data-original-title="admin">A</span>
                </a>
                <a class="permalink" href="/topic/1/welcome-to-your-nodebb/2">
                    <span class="timeago" title="Mon Aug 29 2016 16:39:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)">about 19 hours ago</span>
                </a>
            </p>
            <div class="post-content">
                <p>adsasdasd</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I have this html and I need to remove this line:

```
<i component="topic/pinned" class="fa fa-thumb-tack "></i>
```

Suppose that there are other `<li component>`. So I use JQuery in this way

```
var params.tid=1;

$('li[component="category/topic"][data-tid="'+params.tid+'"]').children('i[component="topic/pinned"]').remove();
```

But it doesn't work! Anyone can help me to remove these line?

EDIT

the script is:

```
$(window).on('action:ajaxify.end', function(event, data) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            socket.on('connectinseriscidatafissadiscussione', function(params) {
                if (new RegExp(/^category\/[0-9]+/).test(data.url)) {
                    console.log("DENTRO IL SOCKET " + params.tid);

                    //$('li[component="category/topic"]').remove();
                    $('li[component="category/topic"][data-tid="'+params.tid+'"]').children('i[component="topic/pinned"]').remove();
                    console.log("PARAMS " + JSON.stringify(params));


                }

            });
        });


    });
```

Comment: The `data-tid` on the `li` is `1`, not `10`, so the selector doesn't match

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes sorry I wrong. The correct data-tid value is 1

Comment: But it doesn't work!

Comment: Could you show more javascript code ? And do you have surround your javascript code with `$( document ).ready()` function ?

Comment: I think can be a loading problem! I edit my code ed I show you my script

Comment: I see 2 console.log in your code. Does it work ? You can see them in your browser console ?

Comment: It doesn't work because the element That I would remove It doesn't remove

Comment: try using [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) `$('li[component="category/topic"][data-tid="'+params.tid+'"]').find('i[component="topic/pinned"]').remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek7yyx19/1/).

I have created a jsfiddle for this and i have used a static `params` variable only to test this code and it works. Check my changes now and try it with your socket. In my jsfiddle it works correct and removes the element you want to remove.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var params = 1;                 
    $('li[component="category/topic"][data-tid="'+params+'"] div h2.title').find('i[component="topic/pinned"]').remove();
});
```